# Allow any name of file to be uploaded if type is as per condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have a requirement where I validate for some condition that if `tabtype` is `Panaromic` then only this name of the file can be uploaded.

> But for my third `tabtype` which is `SitePlot` what I want is, User can upload file with any name

Here is what I tried..

```
var Tabtype = document.getElementById('hdnType').value;

    if (Tabtype == "Panaromic") {
        var validFileName = {
            "120.jpg": 1, "150.jpg": 1, "180.jpg": 1, "210.jpg": 1, "240.jpg": 1,
        }
    }

    if (Tabtype == "Satellite") {
        var validFileName = {
            "55.jpg": 1, "74.jpg": 1, "83.jpg": 1, "935.jpg": 1,
        }
    }

    if (Tabtype == "SitePlot") {
        var validFileName = {
            "":1,
        }
    }
```

But when I upload for Siteplot I get error at this line

```
var fileName = path.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
            if (!validFileName[fileName]) {
                jAlert("Invalid file name" + filename);
            }
```

For full js code. Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8x8v308/)

Comment: need reason for downvote.. Please

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I see no question here. If "Why do I get error?", then we need the error. About your JSFiddle: it is not working, it should be a minimal reproducable example. There is no sense in fiddle if it is just a code which cannot be run and/or debugged.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: please tell me what you didnt understand so that I can explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `validFileName` to `true` and use AND `&&` at `if` condition to check if `validFileName` is a `Boolean`

```
if (Tabtype == "SitePlot") {
  validFileName = true;
}
```

```
var fileName = path.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();

if (typeof validFileName !== "boolean" && !validFileName[fileName]) {
  jAlert("Invalid file name" + filename);
}
```

Comment: What line is unexpected? Note, `validFileName` should probably be a global variable

Answer (score 0):

You can change your logic so that it does not rely on filename equality anymore:

```
function isValidFilename(filename) 
{
    switch (document.getElementById('hdnType').value) 
    {
        case "Panaromic":
            var validNames = ["120.jpg", "150.jpg", "180.jpg", "210.jpg", "240.jpg"];
            return validNames.indexOf(filename) > -1;

        case "Satellite":
            var validNames = ["55.jpg", "74.jpg", "83.jpg", "935.jpg", "240.jpg"];
            return validNames.indexOf(filename) > -1;

        case "SitePlot"
            return true;

        case "OtherExamples":
            return /^\d{1,}\.jpg$/.match(filename); // regular expression
            return filename.Length > 3; // length
            return filename.substring(filename.Length - 4) === ".jpg"; // anything else

        default:
            throw new Error("Wrong Tabtype");
    }
}

var fileName = path.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
if (!isValidFilename(fileName)) {
    jAlert("Invalid file name" + filename);
}
```

Now, "Panaromic" and "Satellite" tabtypes require filename to match their allowed values lists, but "SitePlot" tabtype allows any filenames.

This way, your logic can contain anything: check for exact values, length, file extension, regular expressions etc.

Keep in mind that a user can always bypass this check and upload file with any file name to your server. If filename is important for your system, then you need to validate it at server-side.